# Zend framework 2 call action from other action of the same controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is it possible in ZF2 to call an action from another action of the same controller? 
If yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you can use the forward controller plugin.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html